# Event Triggering from MEF plugin C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, mef

I would like to know how I can trigger event or call any specific function from MEF plugin to/in host application, and I would really appreciate it if you could provide any guideline for this.

Actually I was implementing C# WPF application with plugins by using MEF technology, and I could implement interface to call function in plugins from host application by using interface, export, and import, but need to do trigger any function or event in opposite direction to let host application know any data changes inside plugin.

Thank you in advance and Regards,
Ian R.

Comment: you need to add event declaration into interface and let the MEF plugin implement it/raise it. you then subscribe from the host side against interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you are okay could you please elaborate more on this to find any nice blog for this or to find simple example? I'm pretty beginner for C#.